# Nature of the use of -ing after some 3rd conditional constructions

Tags: conditional-constructions, past-perfect

Good day.

I am a student currently about to finish English Studies at college. I usually have observational competence to whether a sentence is grammatically correct or not, but I am now trying to also learn and develop an explicative competence to some somehow miscellaneous uses and features of English.

I have observed that, when presenting a "reason" for the past perfect part of a 3rd conditional structure, as in the example given below, sometimes the verb comes in its -ing form. I would like to know if there's a specific grammatical rule for this, if there's maybe a semantical reason in which English just conceives and conceptualises that specific experience of reality in a gerund way (in Spanish, my native language, that -ing form would be in past simple) or if it's just something rather arbitrary.

Example: Had it not been for you *forgetting* your keys, we wouldn't have had to sleep on the rough.

Comment: That could also be expressed "Had you not forgotten your keys,..." or "If you hadn't forgotten..." It doesn't have to be a gerund.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty Right then, so if it doesn't have to be a gerund necessarily, is there a meaningful difference between my example and yours? Like a pragmatical difference.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your example sounds very formal. I looked at 'had it not been for' (without quotes) on google ngram viewer and found that it has decreased in frequency for a century or so. In colloquial use, I think most people would say "If you hadn't forgotten" or even "If you didn't forget", though I wouldn't use the latter in writing.

Comment: I'll add that the grammar books I have don't speak of numbered conditionals, but look at the two parts of the conditional more independently.